# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column in where clause Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive an error of

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'requests.access_level_id' in 'where clause': 
SELECT `requests`.* 
  FROM `requests` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `requests`.`from_id` 
  WHERE `requests`.`access_level_id` = 1 
  ORDER BY id DESC
```

Model

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :from_id
end
```

Controller

```
@req = Request.left_outer_joins(:user).where(access_level_id: 1).order('id DESC')
```

How can I remove requests from the `WHERE clause requests.access_level_id = 1`? I just want `access_level_id = 1` to be in the where statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you requested, you can add where clause without `requests` as,

```
@req = Request.left_outer_joins(:user).where('access_level_id = ?', 1).order('id DESC')
```

But its good to keep relative aliasing for access_level_id. If its `users` then please use it like,

```
@req = Request.left_outer_joins(:user).where(users: { access_level_id: 1 }).order('id DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `access_level_id` is field for user, you can replace your query with following:

```
@req = Request.left_outer_joins(:user).where('users.access_level_id = ?', 1).order('id  DESC')
```

By default the fields in where conditions are considered to be belonging to Request method in your query.

Hope this helps you.
Please let me know if you face any issue.